# Geographic coordinates system to Lambert Conformal Conic projected CRS using a transformation matrix

Tags: coordinate-system, lambert-conformal-conic

Given a LCC projection with two standard parallels, is it possible to define a transformation matrix to map any given lat/lon in the covered area into the projected CRS (e.g. similar to a rotation matrix or other affine transformations).
Since the coordinates transformation equation coefficients (e.g.  theta, rho) depend on the input coordinates, I guess it's not possible to exactly calculate such a matrix, but I was wondering if any numerical approximation exists.

Comment: The transformation that you are looking for is not affine. You can approximate an affine transformation from projected to geocentric, since both systems are Cartesian. The first one is 2D, the second is 3D, the conversion between them is not affine but you can approximate. But can't do the same to geographic coordinates. Also, the first approximation will be not a good solution to replace the conversion formulae.

Comment: What about an affine transformation between two projected CRS, e.g. LCC and Transverse Mercator?

Comment: You can approximate, but the relation between both systems is not an affine transformation.

Comment: Thanks, could you point out some literature or hint about those approximated affine transformations?

Comment: Not about the approximation between both systems. Just between 2D Cartesian control points coordinates in two random systems, you can find the parameters of the affine transformation that minimizes the error. See: https://www.accessengineeringlibrary.com/content/book/9780071761123/back-matter/appendix3